# BizTalk AS2 sendport error while transmitting message to customer send port

Tags: biztalk, actionscript-2

The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "" with URL "". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Comment: You are going to have to supply a lot more details than that.

Comment: e.g. What Pipeline are you using, and what are the pipeline components?  But on the face of it, it looks like the URL for the AS2 party is not configured.